# Get Text in GridView Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm having a problem in looping through my gridview. I have this loop in my button.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(GridViewRow row in gvRFPCorpCode.Rows)
        {
            txtCorpCode.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        }
    }
```

But everytime i click on it nothing happens, I want the text on the selected cell be displayed in my textbox. I don't see how is it not working, seems to be that my code is correct. Please do help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem is you're looping over every row, overwriting whatever's in txtCorpCode.Text with each iteration. The GridView has a SelectedRow property, use that instead - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (MSDN description of this property)

Comment: please edit the question and show your markup code. also, please specify which cell's value you want to get.